# WebView & KeyEvents

Tags: javascript, android, webview, keyevent

I'm having issues with KeyCodes in my activity that creates a WebView & loads a URL. I've noticed that when I press a key on the keyboard or a button on my IR remote, it does NOT call the onKeyDown() method in the WebView. I'm guessing it directly calls the underlying JavaScript (which is fine as long as the correct keycodes are being passed down)

The problem I'm having is some keys on my IR remote are just being passed down as 0 (like the Guide, Info, the colored buttons which are all used for playback related options). However, some keys do work (such as the numerical buttons). Any idea where the keyCodes are being hijacked? I checked the EventHub & InputDispatcher, they seem to have the right codes. Do I need to check someplace in the chromium/android_webview code base? Here's a snippet of what I'm using:

```
private class myWV extends WebView
{
    public myWV(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        Log.e("myWV", "onKeyDown: " +keyCode);
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait while we look for available TV channels...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    super.onCreate(icicle);

    mWebView = new myWV(this);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: Calling setJavaScriptEnabled");
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl(mURL);

    // Enable the view
    setContentView(mWebView);
}
```

Would appreciate any tips

Comment: Check documentation of WebView.onKeyDown - it mentions: `Do not rely on this to catch software key presses.` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Which API level or Android version are you working on? As far as I know, 4.0 and 4.1/4.2 have slight differences regarding handling all kinds of events, while great differences between 4.1/4.2 and 4.4, since the later has switched to Chromium Webkit engine.

Comment: @Wie WANG, I'm on 4.4.2. What I know for sure is that these remote key codes work perfectly fine when used in a simple Activity (non WebView based). Somehow, in this app, they are being reinterpreted (maybe within Chromium's webview?). Any ideas where I can put some prints to check further?

Comment: I finally found the place where the WebView makes the native call & see that the ASCII [via event->getUnicodeChar()] value for Guide is 0 (obviously wrong) while for example the letter ‘g’ gets it correctly as 103. It's translateAndSendNativeEvents(). So, I put in a workaround to send the correct ASCII code for my Guide button, but it still didn't work!! I then found that the native code is NOT even using this ASCII value, it just uses the scan-code which is the hardware id & that is correct. I'm still at loss here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the piece of code in Chromium that handles key events. Just added my special keys in there & it now works like a charm